# Calculated member shows all members including where facts do not exist

Tags: ssas, mdx, member, cube

I have created a calculated member that assigns customer type. The problem is that it shows every single member from customer dimension and I have too little experience to fix it.

I want to show only customers that actualy ordered.
e.g. [Measures].[Total Amount]>0 
for currently selected period. e.g. current year. ([Basic Calendar].[Year -  Week -  Date])

Please advise and see formula below.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Customer Type]
 AS IIF( [Measures].[Orders by Customer]=0, "Zero Customer",
            IIF( [Measures].[Orders by Customer]=1, "One Off Customer",  
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>1 and [Measures].[Orders by Customer]<4 , "2 to 3 Orders", 
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>3 and [Measures].[Orders by Customer]<6,  "4 to 5 Orders", 
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>5, "VIP Customer",  "Other"))))), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an 'empty' condition that returns null:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Customer Type]
 AS
            IIF( IsEmpty([Measures].[Orders by Customer]), null,
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]=0, "Zero Customer",
            IIF( [Measures].[Orders by Customer]=1, "One Off Customer",  
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>1 and [Measures].[Orders by Customer]<4 , "2 to 3 Orders", 
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>3 and [Measures].[Orders by Customer]<6,  "4 to 5 Orders", 
            IIF([Measures].[Orders by Customer]>5, "VIP Customer",  "Other")))))), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```